# How to execute multiple mySQL queries in one PHP script

Tags: php, mysql

Currently, I have the following structure in my `PHP` script, I would like one `query` to execute and if successful the next one should execute.

The following is my current code, but how can I add a simple
conditional that would allow the second query to execute after the
delete query?

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "dbname";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "DELETE FROM Table1" ;

$sql = " INSERT INTO Table1 (tbcolm, , tbcolm2, tbcolm3)
         SELECT `column1`, `column2`,`column3` FROM Table3 ";




if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: the trick is, naming your variables differently

Comment: How so? You mean the $sql?

Comment: you've named your different SQL statements the same variable name (`$sql`)

Comment: How do I include the second variable in $conn->query ($sql, $sql2) == TRUE ?

Comment: `$conn->query($sql1); $conn->query($sql2);`, that's it.

Comment: Either put them in one sql statement or execute both queries separately..

Comment: @u_mulder I get a syntax error when doing this `if ($conn->query($sql); $conn->query($sql2); === TRUE) {`

Comment: I’m just confused if that is where you wanted me to put it

Comment: @BradSlen that's because you have a semi-colon inside the if statement parenthesis

Answer (score 0):

You can use mysqli multi_query, as stated in PHP Manual:

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.multiple-statement.php

Be sure to add a ; at the end of your strings, and use the concatenating assignment operator (.=) on the second $sql variable.

It should look like this:

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM Table1;";

$sql .= "INSERT INTO Table1 (tbcolm, , tbcolm2, tbcolm3)
         SELECT 'column1', 'column2','column3' FROM Table3;";

if ($mysqli->multi_query($sql)) {

 /* success code here */

}
```

If the first argument fails, the next one won't be queried, as stated in:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php